# Alfresco Add Category based on Tag

Tags: javascript, tags, alfresco, rules

I would like to create a script to use as a folder rule to add a category based on the tag.

This script successfully adds the category to the file.

```
var catNodeRef = search.findNode("workspace://SpacesStore/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
var categories= document.properties["cm:categories"];

if (categories == null ) {
categories = new Array (); }
     
categories.push(catNodeRef);
document.properties["cm:categories"] = categories;
document.save();
};
```

However, when I add the findTaggedNodes, the script fails.

```
var taggedNodes =  findTaggedNodes("workspace://SpacesStore/XXXXXXXXXtagnumber");
var taggable= document.properties["cm:taggable"];
if (taggedNodes == "workspace://SpacesStore/XXXXXXXXXtagnumber" )

{
var catNodeRef = search.findNode("workspace://SpacesStore/88b392ce-a50c-4079-a8cb-8a18faafc154");
var categories= document.properties["cm:categories"];

if (categories == null ) {
categories = new Array (); }
     
categories.push(catNodeRef);
document.properties["cm:categories"] = categories;
document.save();
};
```

I have also tried

```
var taggable= document.properties.hastag = "aaf observatory";

if(var taggable)
{
var catNodeRef = search.findNode("workspace://SpacesStore/88b392ce-a50c-4079-a8cb-8a18faafc154");
var categories= document.properties["cm:categories"];

if (categories == null ) {
categories = new Array (); }
     
categories.push(catNodeRef);
document.properties["cm:categories"] = categories;
document.save();
};
```

Any help would be appreciated. (NOTE: I am not a developer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findTaggedNodes` don't work in javascript, you can use it in Java with `TaggingService` , in JavaScript you need to use `search.findNode(TAG_NODE_REF)` to get the node of the tag with the `nodeRef`.

`var taggable = document.properties["cm:taggable"];` return a collection of tags, you cannot compare it with string value. you need a loop to compare if the collection contain same node et use `node1.equals(node2)`

You find script here :

```
var nodeTag = search.findNode('workspace://SpacesStore/XXXXXXXXXtagnumber');
//Get Tags of document 
var documentTags = document.properties["cm:taggable"];

for each(var tag in documentTags) {

    if(tag.equals(nodeTag)) {

        //Tag is found in document, add the category with function 
        addCAtegory(document, "workspace://SpacesStore/REF_ID_CATEGORY");
    }
}

function addCAtegory(node, categoryNodeRef) {
    
    var catNodeRef = search.findNode(categoryNodeRef);
    var categories= node.properties["cm:categories"];

    if (categories == null ) {
        categories = new Array (); 
    }
     
    categories.push(catNodeRef);
    node.properties["cm:categories"] = categories;
    node.save();
}
```